# Fetch all the value from database to webgrid of ASP MVC ASPX

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, webgrid

Hi I am getting only the last value from the database in the webgrid. I have used foreach to get all the value from the database and binded it to the webgrid but it is showing only the last value  in the webgrid . Please guide me

```
 var listobject = list ;

  foreach (var m in ViewBag.Model)
  {
      var  list = new[] 
                {                     

                    new { Name = m.Name, Genre =m.Genre }                        

                };
      listobject = list;

  }


  WebGrid studentGrid = new WebGrid();
  studentGrid.Bind(listobject, autoSortAndPage: false, rowCount: 3);
```

%>

```
        <%= studentGrid.GetHtml(columns: 
new WebGridColumn[]
    {
        studentGrid.Column("Name", "name"),
        studentGrid.Column("Genre", "Genre"),

    })
```

%>

Answer (score 1):

On every iteration, you reset "list", which is why you are losing any value assigned to it on the previous iteration. Just pass in ViewBag.Model:

```
var grid = new WebGrid(ViewBag.Model);

@grid.GetHtml()
```